# ACTION_CHOOSER vs ACTION_VIEW intents (Open vs open with...)

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have deployed an Android app that is designed to view files, some users reporting that my app isn't appearing when they try to open a file but does appear when selecting `Open with...`.

---

For example, when I try to open a file in some apps I am presented with a dialog like this:

[image]

When I press `Open with...` I am presented with a dialog like this:

[image]

---

I think what is happening here is the `Open with...` is starting an `ACTION_CHOOSER` intent whereas pressing the file starts an `ACTION_VIEW` intent.

My questions are:

1. Is my assumption surrounding the `ACTION_CHOOSER` reasonable?
2. Why do some apps appear in `ACTION_CHOOSER` that don't appear in `ACTION_VIEW`?
3. Is the `ACTION_VIEW` list somehow dependent on a device?
4. If so, what would cause my app to not appear in this list?

For reference, my activity's intent filter looks like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:scheme="content" />

            <data
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"
                android:scheme="file" />

            <!-- about a hundred other file types -->

        <intent-filter>
```

Comment: unrelated to your question. but is */xml a valid mimeType? (asterisks before a defined subtype)

Comment: Ahh no, my bad. I included the manifest I was playing around with, I've just updated the question with the production code.